# windows embedded compact 7.0 software de programación

Tags: c#

eh adquirido una PC con el windows embedded compact 7.0 instalado.
He tratado de instalar un programa diseñados que tengo en C# me dice que no es compatible con windows embedded lo cree en C++ y me da ese mismo error.
¿Visual estudio no tiene una plataforma de programación para este versión de windows? 
Gracias,

Answer (score 0):

Si la tiene pero esta tecnologia esta algo obsoleta
Deberas remontarte a `Visual Studio 2008` para poder tener un tipo de proyecto compatible con Win CE

[Windows Mobile App Development Part 1: Creating your first application](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43357/Windows-Mobile-App-Development-Part-1-Creating-you)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como veras en VS2008 si tienes template para este tipo de desarrollo

Por el lado de C++ creo que hay algo mas

[Building Windows CE 6 or 7 Smart Device Application with Visual Studio 2012 (Part 1)](https://web.archive.org/web/20201205155928/http://geekswithblogs.net/WernerWillemsens/archive/2013/09/13/building-windows-ce-6-or-7-smart-device-application-with.aspx)

pero la verdad lo veo bastante complicado

Comment: hice la aplicación en blend para visual estudio 2017, no me da error pero no carga la aplicación.
Trate de instalar visual estudio 2008 tengo Windows 2010 me da error de instalación.
Alguna idea? gracias.

Comment: Blend y VS2017 no funciona en Windows Compact

Comment: no deberia fallar la instalacion de VS2008, ejecutaste como admin de la pc? vuelve a intentarlo usando la opcion de selecionar que componente agregar, quita lo que no utilices